# How can I skip logging my executable prints to the Mac Console

Tags: macos, launchd

I'm creating a Mac Launch Agent for my app. The Launch agent works fine. But the executable bin file prints some console messages,when the exe is started in terminal and all those messages are logged to Mac Console. How can i skip logging those messages to the Mac Console ..?

I have tried adding a shell script as a Lauch Agent, which starts the exe, so that executable won't log messages to the console. But the script doesn't starts the bin.

This is my Launch Agent plist file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
 <plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
      <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.myapp</string>
  <key>Program</key>
  <string>./bin/MyBin</string>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/Applications/MyApp/</string>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  </dict>
  </plist>
```

Comment: What generates the messages; your code or some library code?

Comment: My Code.Actually i need those messages in case of some problems.

Comment: Then why not write them to a file (in, say, `~Library/Caches`) rather than to `stderr`?

Comment: you mean, changing cout prints to a file..? That would require a lot of Code Changes, my Code Base is somewhat bigger, a little over 100 files ,each having more than 1000 lines of Code. I need a option not altering my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the default treatment of stdout and stderr for launchd jobs by adding the `StandardOutPath` and `StandardErrorPath` keys to your .plist file.  To discard all output, add this:

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/dev/null</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/dev/null</string>
```

You could also redirect one or both to a log file.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is as Gordon Davisson said above. However when i need to start more than one executable, then its possible by shell script.

This was my Script :

```
  #!/bin/bash
  cd /Applications/MyApp/
  dates=`date`
  echo "Exe Started at ::: ${dates}" > proc.log
  # Starting Exe
  ./bin/MyBin 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null & echo $! > proc.pid
```

I was having trouble with this script. I can see the proc.log filling up, but no sign of my App. Surprisingly when i removed the '&' from the script ,launch agent started working fine.

```
   ./bin/MyBin 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null & echo $! > proc.pid
```

Changed to

```
   ./bin/MyBin 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

I m not sure why Mac is making the background process as a difference in launchd. The Script was & is working fine as it is, when i manually run it.

Comment: launchd expects the processes it starts to stay in the foreground, so it can keep an eye on them.  If your script spawns a background process and then exits, launchd thinks the task has finished and it cleans up (i.e. kills) any leftover background processes... and then maybe restarts the main script. Solution: don't background the actual job! If you must background it, add `<key>KeepAlive</key><false/><key>AbandonProcessGroup</key><true/>` to the .plist to change launchd's default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The output can only be redirected before the process begins.  In this case if you don't want to change all your code then the executable for your launch agent will need to be a script.  The script can then redirect as needed, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
# redirect to a log file, /dev/null, or wherever it should go;
# this is just an example log file destination
`/usr/bin/dirname $0`/run_real_agent > /tmp/my_agent.$$.log 2>&1
```

Comment: i have already done this man, ./bin/Mybin 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null in my script, the problem is script is not starting the Mybin.

Comment: Note what I did in mine though...I used `dirname` to resolve the path completely.  If you just use `./` it is interpreted as a relative path, and it is relative to *whatever directory is current when the script is run by the system* (which could be anything).  What happens if you take the example above but replace `/run_real_agent` with `/bin/Mybin`?

Comment: This is my script

#!/bin/bash
cd /Applications/MyApp/
dates=`date`
echo "Exe Started at ::: ${dates}" > proc.log
# Starting Exe
./bin/MyBin 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null & echo $! > proc.pid

Comment: LaunchAgents start at "/", if you print the pwd in a Launch Agent Script, you can see that

Comment: Okay, a `cd` is equivalent.  Do you see any other evidence that the shell script even runs, such as the "Exe Started" message?  Maybe `launchd` requires an explicit `ProgramArguments` array with `/bin/bash` as the first argument and the script name as the 2nd.

Comment: yeah , the script is running, i can see it from the log. Is it possible that i can redirect my program output /dev/null using ProgramArguments, i tried it though, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: The redirection syntax is a shell feature and `launchd` is most likely passing the arguments to something like `execlp()` so I doubt redirection would work up front.  Once your script is running the redirection should be solvable there however.  You said the `MyBin` executable still doesn't run?  At first glance your script seems OK but I'm kind of guessing where your script's new-lines are due to comment formatting; you might consider updating your original question with the script instead.  Also, temporarily remove the script's redirection in case it's masking an error like "file not found".

Comment: Thanks Kevin, redirection is no problem, it was the '&' . Thanks for your effort.